# Container width not changing using pdf package

Tags: flutter

I am using the package pdf and I need to insert a container that should be the complete page width.

I am trying as follows:

```
  Container(
      width: 1000,
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: PdfColors.black),
      ),
      child:
      Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            pw.Text("O:",
                style:
                pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 10),


          ]
      )
  ),
```

I have changed the Container width from 10 to 1000 and 1200, but the container only grows until the shown position

[image]

I don´t understand how to manage widths and heights using the pdf package.

Comment: Can you please attach the whole code of that classs?

Comment: it is very long , 1940 code lines

Comment: For better understanding i need to see you code .

Comment: @AkshayGupta, tell me what part of the code is interesting to you and i will put it here

Comment: So you just have to create custom pdf using pdf package right?

Comment: if you can initiate chat then we can communicate there.

Comment: @AkshayGupta, yes it is a custom pdf using the pdf package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254608/discussion-between-akshay-gupta-and-mvasco).